# The convolution of a absolutely continuous measure and a probability measure is absolutely continuous

Tags: measure-theory

I met an excercise in the book by Rabi Bhattacharya and Edward C. Waymire. Suppose that $\mu,\nu$ are probbaility measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$, with $\nu$ absolutely continuous with pdf $f$, i.e., $d\nu=f(x)dx$. How to show that the convolution, $\mu\ast \nu$, is also absolutely continuous? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $\ A\ $ is a measurable subset of $\ \mathbb{R}^d\ $, then
\begin{align}
\mu*\nu(A)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{A-y} d\nu(x)d\mu(y)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{A-y}f(x)dxd\mu(y)\ .
\end{align}
If $\ A\ $ has Lebesgue measure $0$ what is the value of this integral?

Comment: Many thanks, it showed that the convolution is absolutely continuous. By the way, what's its pdf?

Comment: \begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{A-y}f(x)dxd\mu(y)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_Af(x-y)dxd\mu(y)\\
&=\int_A\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x-y)d\mu(y)dx\ ,
\end{align}
which gives
$$ 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x-y)d\mu(y)
$$
as the density of $\ \mu*\nu\ $.

Comment: I got it. Many thanks.